# Sort case class by node from its JsValue field

Tags: json, scala, sorting

I have a sequence of case class A (id: UUID, profile: String, data: JsValue)

I'd like to sort the sequence by **updated** from the JsValue data field

data field looks like this

```
{
 "doors":2,
 "color":"Black",
 "updated":"2019-09-24T15:59:21+0200",
 "username":"John",
 "year":2016
}
```

I tried
`sequenceOfA.sortWith(_.data \ "updated" < _.data \ "updated")` but that doesn't work because < is not a member of play's JsLookupResult

Casting it to String doesn't work either

```
sequenceOfA.sortWith((_.data \ "updated").as[String] < (_.data \ "updated").as[String])
```

What would be the most idiomatic way to do this in Scala?

Comment: Will it be ok if case class is changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you would need is to handle absent field. This can be done via more safe approach with explicitly handling:

```
  sequenceOfA.sortWith { case (left, right) =>
    val leftUpdate = (left.data \ "update").validate[String].asOpt
    val rightUpdate = (right.data \ "update").validate[String].asOpt
    leftUpdate -> rightUpdate match {
      case (Some(left), Some(right)) => left < right
      case (None, Some(_)) => true // objects with `update` absent field goes first 
      case (Some(_), None) => false // objects with `update` present field goes after absent field
    }
  }
```

Or just invoke `get` method, which might throw an exception - which is highly unrecommended:

```
sequenceOfA.sortWith((m \ "updated").as[String].get < (_.data \ "updated").as[String].get)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

A potential solution could be:

```
// Input is Seq[A] i.e val input: Seq[A]
// ConvertToTimestamp is a method which takes time as string and returns timestamp. 
//This is required since time is in string and also timezones are involved. 
//So this method will convert time string to UTC time(in epochs)
// def convertToTimeStamp(time: String): Long

val updated: Seq[Long] = A.map(value => (value.data \ "updated").as[String]).map(x => convertToTimestamp(x)) // fetch value 

val pairs = input zip updated // List of ordered tuple

val sortedInput = pairs.sort(sortBy(pair => pair._2)).map(_._1).toSeq // sort using timestamp
```

The above solution assumes that `updated` field is not empty. If forsome input it is empty, change the function where we are parsing this field(while computing `updated` value as shown in above to have a default value based on the requirement(either 0 if you want such records to come first or `Duration.Inf` if you want those records to come last).

Let me know if it helps!!